# How to switch textFieldStyle to a TextField when user taps the field?

Tags: textfield, swiftui

I'm trying to change the TextField style from `.plain` to `.roundedCorners` when the user taps on the TextField.
The TextField itself is initially disabled (.plain style) and when the user taps on it, should enable editing mode (which is working) and change to (.roundedCorners style)

I've tried changing the style based on TextField state `(if disabled ? .plain : .roundedCorners)`, but that doesn't seem to be working

```
.textFieldStyle(self.listState.editingScreenshot == nil ? .plain : .roundedCorners)
```

I get the following error when using inline if statement:

> Type 'StaticMember' has no member
>   'roundedCorners'.

Answer (score 2):

Using style conditionally may be challenging, I prefer this approach, which is also much more customizable:

In this example I use a darker border color depending on activation, and in the second example, I just remove the style completely:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var active1: Bool = false
    @State private var value1 = ""

    @State private var active2: Bool = false
    @State private var value2 = ""

    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Spacer()

            Text("Field 1")
            TextField("", text: $value1, onEditingChanged: { self.active1 = $0 }).padding().overlay(TextFieldBorder(rounded: active1))

            Text("Field 2")
            TextField("", text: $value2, onEditingChanged: { self.active2 = $0 }).padding().overlay(TextFieldBorder(rounded: active2))

            Spacer()
        }.background(Color(white: 0.9))
    }
}

struct TextFieldBorder: View {
    var rounded = true

    var body: some View {
        Group {
            if rounded {
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10).stroke(Color.black)
            } else {
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10).stroke(Color.gray)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To remove the style completely:

```swift
struct TextFieldBorder: View {
    var rounded = true

    var body: some View {
        Group {
            if rounded {
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10).stroke(Color.black)
            } else {
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10).stroke(Color.clear)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The static member you are looking for is `roundedBorder`:

```
public static var roundedBorder: RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle.Member { get }
```